# Launching two query via java code

Tags: java, postgresql

I want to execute two queries in my `PostgreSQL` database via code java.
The first one create a temporary `view` and the second one get some data from this view.
This is my code:

```
String sql = "create or replace temp view recap as "
                       + "select id_salarie, concat(nom, ' ', prenom) as np, hour_salary, id_chantier, id_activity, SUM(nb_heures) as s_hn, SUM(nb_heures_s) as s_hs, value_update, (hour_salary*SUM(nb_heures)) as cost_hn, ((hour_salary*value_update)*SUM(nb_heures_s)) as cost_hs "
                       + "from pointage_full pf, salarie s, hs_increase hsi "
                       + "where s.id = pf.id_salarie "
                       + "and hsi.etat = 1 "
                       + "and id_chantier = "+this.idProject+" and id_salarie <> id_chef "
                       + "group by id_salarie, np, hour_salary, id_activity, id_chantier, value_update "
                       + "order by id_salarie DESC;"
                       + ""//=================execute the second query to get costs from created view===========================
                       + "select id_activity, sum(cost_hn) as sm_cost_hn, sum(cost_hs) as sm_cost_hs, (sum(cost_hn)+sum(cost_hs)) as cost_activity "
                       + "from recap "
                       + "group by id_activity "
                       + "order by id_activity asc;";
ResultSet res = state.executeQuery(sql);
while (res.next()) {
   //---doing my stuff...
}
```

But I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results returned by the query.
```

Comment: You need to use a **transaction** and execute two queries. You also need to learn about **prepared statements** and SQL injection - to which your code is currently vulnerable.

Comment: Further to your comment, note the difference between [`executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) and [`executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()).

Comment: So I should create the view using `executeUpdate()` and then get the result using `executeQuery()` ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute more than one statement with a single `executeXXX()` call - especially not a DDL statement and a query.

But you don't need to create that (temporary) view in the first place. Also the `order by` inside the view is also useless as you are re-ordering the rows in the final statement again.

You can do what you want with one single statement:

```
select id_activity, sum(cost_hn) as sm_cost_hn, sum(cost_hs) as sm_cost_hs, (sum(cost_hn)+sum(cost_hs)) as cost_activity 
from (
  select id_salarie, 
         concat(nom, ' ', prenom) as np, 
         hour_salary, 
         id_chantier, 
         id_activity, 
         SUM(nb_heures) as s_hn, 
         SUM(nb_heures_s) as s_hs, 
         value_update, 
         (hour_salary*SUM(nb_heures)) as cost_hn, 
         ((hour_salary*value_update)*SUM(nb_heures_s)) as cost_hs 
  from pointage_full pf, salarie s, hs_increase hsi 
  where s.id = pf.id_salarie 
  and hsi.etat = 1 
  and id_chantier = ?
  and id_salarie <> id_chef 
  group by id_salarie, np, hour_salary, id_activity, id_chantier, value_update 
) as recap
group by id_activity 
order by id_activity asc;
```

You should also use a `PreparedStatement` instead of concatenating parameters into your SQL. If you have the above query in a String, you can do something like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY);
pstmt.setInt(1, this.idProject);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next() 
{
  // process result set
}
```

I'm pretty sure this will be faster than first creating a temp view and then querying that.

Comment: you're  absolutely right, thank you very much I didn't know you can do that. thnx again.

Comment: @SlimenTunis: See here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-SUBQUERIES and here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html for more information and other ways to do this.

Comment: @SlimenTunis: you might also want to have a look at this: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2015-02/modern-sql